# wxpython: centering text within a panel within a sizer

Tags: python, wxpython, panel, center, sizer

It seems to me that the following code should display text right in the centre of the window; that is, in the centre of the inner panel. It doesn't however, and I'm wondering why not. If you run the code, you'll see a white panel in the middle of the frame, 150px by 150px. I do not want this area to change in size at all, but when I go about adding some text (uncommenting the `txt` variable in the middle of the snippet)the panel invariably shrinks to fit the text. Even specifying the size of the `StaticText` to match the panel isn't a solution because the text doesn't then centre-align.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)




        self.rootPanel = wx.Panel(self)

        innerPanel = wx.Panel(self.rootPanel,-1, size=(150,150), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        innerPanel.SetBackgroundColour('WHITE')
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # I want this line visible in the CENTRE of the inner panel
        #txt = wx.StaticText(innerPanel, id=-1, label="TEXT HERE",style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER, name="")

        hbox.Add(innerPanel, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        vbox.Add(hbox, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)

        self.rootPanel.SetSizer(vbox)
        vbox.Fit(self)

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'wxBoxSizer.py')
        frame.Show(True)
        frame.Center()
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to add a couple spacers to make it work.

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)

        self.rootPanel = wx.Panel(self)

        innerPanel = wx.Panel(self.rootPanel,-1, size=(150,150), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        innerPanel.SetBackgroundColour('WHITE')
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        innerBox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # I want this line visible in the CENTRE of the inner panel
        txt = wx.StaticText(innerPanel, id=-1, label="TEXT HERE",style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER, name="")
        innerBox.AddSpacer((150,75))
        innerBox.Add(txt, 0, wx.CENTER)
        innerBox.AddSpacer((150,75))
        innerPanel.SetSizer(innerBox)

        hbox.Add(innerPanel, 0, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        vbox.Add(hbox, 1, wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 5)

        self.rootPanel.SetSizer(vbox)
        vbox.Fit(self)

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, 'wxBoxSizer.py')
        frame.Show(True)
        frame.Center()
        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks Mike. I spent ages trying to do this, spacer approach works fine. Can't help feeling however that there should be a one-liner to do something as ubiquitous this.

Comment: Well, you could create the spacers and then then use the sizer's AddMany() method to add all three. There may be a wrapper I'm forgetting about or maybe SizedControls would work. I haven't really used the latter though.